# Can't open binary file in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, binaryfiles

I have a binary file called signatures, and I tried to open it in my program, based on user-input. 
I realized it doesn't actually open when I input the exact file name and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code I wrote to test the matter:

```
char buffer[1024];

fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

FILE* file = fopen(buffer, "rb");
if(file){
    printf("worked");
    fclose(file);
}
```

when I type in "signatures" the file still doesn't open. 
However, if I do the following:

```
FILE* file = fopen("signatures","rb");
```

it actually does open. What could be the problem?

I'm running this on ubuntu 18.04 on a virtualbox virtual machine with windows 10 as host.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you, that actually solved it .